# Fix a bug in fixed header with anchor function in my responsive design layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[my responsive design layout](http://www.aidahk.org/dev/testing/mission.html)

The above link is my responsive design layout.

The height of fixed header is adjusted according to pc, tablet & mobile version. By the same token, the anchor function is adjusted from fixed header. There is a bug in the anchor function. When I narrow the width of a web browser, the header will become higher. The anchor function is not work automatic that I need to click F5 to refresh the web to active that function. How can I fix the bug?

Below is my css & js coding:

```
    var menuContainer = $('header').height();

function scrollToAnchor(anchorName) {
  var aTag = $("div[name='" + anchorName + "']");
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: aTag.offset().top - menuContainer
  }, 'slow');
  console.log(anchorName);
}
```

css coding

```
#subnav {
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 120%;

}
#submenu ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    width: 650px;
}
#submenu li {
    float: left;
}
#submenu li a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-right: 1px solid #294C52;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.submenu-active {
    background-color: #294C52;
    color: #FFFFFF; 
}
a {
  color: #294C52;
}
```

Comment: use the `resize` event listener, and place this inside `menuContainer = $('header').height();`. that way when the user resizes the window, the header height is calculated each time.

Comment: would u give me a answer?

Comment: try my answer and if it doesn't work tell me what happens exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var menuContainer = $('header').height();

function scrollToAnchor(anchorName) {
  var aTag = $("div[name='" + anchorName + "']");
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: aTag.offset().top - menuContainer
  }, 'slow');
  console.log(anchorName);
}

$(window).on('resize', function(event) {
   menuContainer = $('header').height();
});
```

Now depending on when you call the function it should work. If you want it to work automatically on resize call the function inside the event handler.